# Encyclopedia of Mathematics?(non-Alphabetical)

Tags: soft-question

Do you know any Encyclopedia of Mathematics which is in non-alphabetical order, like it starts from basic mathematics and then goes up to very advanced level.

And what's the difference between say, if I am studying calculus from Mathematical Encyclopedia and if I am studying calculus from a university based calculus textbook?

Wikipedia is an excellent resource for Encyclopedia of mathematics,but using it is very confusing, as on these pages([page 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_mathematics_topics) and [page 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_mathematics)) there are too many links and it gets quite confusing, from where to start and where to finish. Can you guide me, on how to properly use Wikipedia as Encyclopedia of Mathematics?

Comment: The Princeton Companion is not a bad substitute.

Answer (score 1):

The [*Encyklopädie der mathematischen Wissenschaften mit Einschluss ihrer Anwendungen*](https://archive.org/details/encyklomath101encyrich) (20+ volumes) was organized from basic to advanced, as was its [French translation](http://gallica.bnf.fr/Search?q=Encyclop%C3%A9die+des+sciences+math%C3%A9matiques+pures+et+appliqu%C3%A9es). It's a bit dated though.

Nowadays there is also the Russian [*Encyclopaedia of Mathematical Sciences*](http://link.springer.com/bookseries/855) (VINITI, translated by Springer, 80+ volumes).

They contain no proofs nor exercises, so are quite unsuited to studying what you would in a textbook. (Likewise Wikipedia; even Bourbaki is not meant for this.)